# How to pass a json file through ajax as Multipart and retrive the file in servlet (jsp)

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, servlets

Please find the code,

```
json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: "jsnservlt",
    data: json,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function(dataa) {
    var resp =JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(resp);

        alert(dataa);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});
```

> How to retrieve the json in servlet?

Comment: what is your question and what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Just listen for a POST request to the jsnservlt endpoint?

Comment: @Ravi I just want to pass a json file to servlet and count the number of elements in that file  return the count !! Using Ajax call

Comment: In the servlet, check whether the incoming connection is multipart, if yes, check how many files are there, and get the files one by one as stream and store it in a file.